# Convertir a String un DateTime SQL con Jquery

Tags: jquery, datetime

Recibo de SQL un resultado de este tipo: `/Date(1503090145770)/` y quisiera mostrarlo en formato de fecha y hora.

Comment: ¿Estás obteniendo un JSON y uno de las propiedades lo trae de esa manera?

Comment: Siii, obtengo en JSON: ultimaactualizacion: /Date(1503090145770)/

Comment: No está demás que agregues el código de cómo construyes el JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer ese valor es la representación de milisegundos de una fecha.

Puedes crear una nueva instancia de `Date();` usando javascript.

Gracias a esta [página](http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/#.WZdmfijyjIU), podemos ver el siguiente ejemplo:

```
console.log(new Date(1503090145770));

// Resultado:
Fri Aug 18 2017 16:02:25 GMT-0500 (Hora est. Pacífico, Sudamérica)
```

Comment: Y cómo quito el /Date(1503090145770)/???

Comment: @EriK, edita tu pregunta agregando el objeto JSON que recibes.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda!
Al final logré resolverlo un poco como me comentaban abajo pero con una leve modificación:

```
        var dateString = time.substr(6);
        var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString));
        var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = currentTime.getDate();
        var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
        var hour = currentTime.getHours();
        var min = currentTime.getMinutes();
        var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + hour + ":" + min + " " + "a.m"/"p.m";
```

Donde time es mi fecha tipo : /Date(1503090145770)/. Obtuve los digitos, con parseint los pasé a entero (ya que era una cadena) y por último usé new Date como me sugirieron, muchas gracias!